# Looking for firefox plugin that redirects links to https for certain domain

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, https, url-rewriting

There is one or two websites where which support both http and https where i want to use https, but where links, redirects, js redirects ... keep sending me to http-locations.

Do any of you know of a firefox plugin which changes links with http for a certain domain to the corresponding link with https ?

For example: 
I click `http://www.domain.com/index.php` -> it takes me to `https://www.domain.com/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Redirector**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5064):

> This can be useful for instance to
>   skip confirmation pages after posting
>   messages on message boards, skipping
>   ad pages that appear before you can
>   view content on certain sites,
>   **redirecting from http to https on sites where you always want the https
>   version**, redirecting from one
>   hostname to another for proxy servers,
>   or just anywhere where it takes you
>   two or more clicks to get to what you
>   want.

Answer (score 1):

NoScript [can do this](http://noscript.net/faq#qa6_3):

> Q:   Can NoScript force some sites to always use HTTPS?
>
> A:   Yes, just open *NoScript Options|Advanced|HTTPS|Behavior*, entering the sites you want to force in the topmost box, and those you want to always leave alone in the bottom one.
>
> You can use space-separated simple strings, which will be matched as "starts with...", glob patterns like `*.noscript.net` and full-fledged regular expressions. If, for instance, you want HTTPS to be forced on every Google application excluding Search and iGoogle, you can put
>
> ```
> *.google.com
> ```
>
> in the "Force" box and
>
> ```
> www.google.com/search www.google.com/ig
> ```
>
> in the "Never" box (the latter can be of course rewritten as a
>
> ```
> ^https?://www\.google\.com/(?:search|ig)\b.*
> ```
>
> regular expression).